# Clojure: Working with vector and ref

Tags: vector, clojure, refs

Please someone who worked with **ref** and **vector** could help-me ?

This vector in each line there is a `(ref {:desc "text" :amount double})`:

```
[#<Ref@1cda773e: {:desc "DESC1", :amount 100}
 #<Ref@468dd81: {:desc "DESC2", :amount 200}
 #<Ref@1e95e716: {:desc "DESC3",:amount -50}>]
```

Is it possible take all amounts above and put it in a new vector like this : [`100, 200, -50]`.

Working with refs is quite difficult and I don't know to to access them.

Comment: Have you tried deref?  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref

Comment: Yes, I did. Its hard to access each one of the refs take the amount and transform in a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
user=> (def data [{:desc "DESC1", :amount 100} {:desc "DESC2", :amount 200} {:desc "DESC3",:amount -50}])
#'user/data
user=> (def my-refs (map #(ref %) data))
#'user/my-refs
user=> (vec (map #(-> % deref :amount) my-refs))
[100 200 -50]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time ! now I can finish here.

Comment: `vec` + `map` could be replaced with `mapv`: `(mapv #(-> % deref :amount) my-refs)` .. or like this: `(mapv (comp :amount deref) my-refs)`